# Does EventStoreDB provide message ordering by an event-key on the consumer side?

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I have been exploring EventStoreDB and trying to understand more about the ordering of messages on the consumer side. Read about `persistent` subscriptions and also the `Pinned` consumer strategy [here](https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v21.6/docs/persistent-subscriptions/#concepts).

I have a scenario wherein inventory updates get pushed to eventstore and different streams get created by the different unique inventoryIds in the inventory event.

[image]

We have multiple consumers with the same consumerGroup name to read these inventory events. We are using Pinned Persistent Subscription with `ResolveLinkTos` enabled.

My question:

- Will every message from a particular stream always go to the same consumer instance of the consumerGroup?
- If the answer to the above question is yes, will every message from that particular stream reach the particular consumer instance in the same order as the events were ingested?

Answer (score 6):

The documentation has a warning that ordered message processing using persistent subscriptions is not guaranteed. Any strategy delivers messages with the best-effort level of ordering guarantees, if applicable.

There are a few reasons for this, some of those are:

- Spreading out messages across consumer groups lead to a non-linearised checkpoint commit. It means that some messages can be processed before other messages.
- Persistent subscriptions attempt to buffer messages, but when a timeout happens on the client side, the whole buffer is redelivered, which can eventually break the processing order
- Built-in retry policies essentially can break the message order at any time

Most event log-based brokers, if not all, don't even attempt to guarantee ordered message delivery across multiple consumers. I often hear "but Kafka does it", ignoring the fact that Kafka delivers messages from one partition to at most one consumer in a group. There's no load balancing of one partition between multiple consumers due to exactly the same issue. That being said, EventStoreDB is still not a broker, but a database for events.

So, here are the answers:

> Will every message from a particular stream always go to the same consumer instance of the consumer group?

No. It might work most of the time, but it will eventually break.

> will every message from that particular stream reach the particular consumer instance in the same order as the events were ingested?

Most of the time, yes, but again, if a message is being retried, you might get the next message before the previous one is Acked.

Overall, load-balancing ordered processing of messages, which aren't pre-partitioned on the server is not an easy task. At most, you get messages re-delivered if the checkpoint fails to persist at some point, and the consumers restart.